# Angular Material Themes - get current primary color

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Currently I have 2 themes:
Light:

```
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue, A700);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-orange, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);
```

Dark:

```
$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$dark-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$dark-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);
```

Sometimes I use my default theme primary color as follows:

```
.extend-toolbar {
  background-color:  mat-color($candy-app-primary);
  color: white;
}
```

but if I change the user theme (e.g setting the theme to dark) - the css class will still take the default theme primary color. **(always uses the `$candy-app-primary`, altough the theme was changed to DARK).**

Any way to take the primary class of the current theme, whatever it is?

Comment: you can try and check out this [link](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to create in your global stylesheet a class which apply the background color of your theme

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in the theme file, to make it work for both light and dark:

```
footer {
  background-color: mat-color($primary);
}

.dark {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
  background-color: #121212;
  color: white;

  footer {
    background-color: mat-color($dark-primary);
  }
}
```

.dark would be the class you use to switch the application to dark mode (or any other theme). Footer can be changed to any other selector.